# CentOS root user crontab for mysqldump

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, bash, cron

I am using CentOS 6.6.
I am trying to set up a crontab. I made an .sh script which runs perfectly when executed manually. 
The command is following:

`mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --hex-blob --flush-logs --master-data=2 -u root -p'password' database1 > database2.sql`

However, when I tried to set it up in /etc/crontab file, it won't run.
Here are the contents of crontab file.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
* * * * * root /home/user/public_html/default1.sh
```

Also, I would like this script to execute in directory

```
/home/user/public_html
```

My script is called default1.sh, and I put it in /home/user/public_html directory.

My goal is to execute this command (or now default1.sh script) as a root user in /home/user/public_html every minute.

Comment: You don't have an NFS-mounted home directory, by any chance?

Comment: @MadHatter No, I don't have.

Comment: OK, then that's not it; just checking.

Comment: How do you launch it manually? Can you report all steps? And how do you know it won't run? What is the expected result that you don't see?

Comment: I launch it by changing the directory in terminal, and launching the command afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There several things you need to check:

1. Make sure your script has an appropriate permissions. You need to have an `x` (at least for user) to be executable.
2. Make sure `mysqldump` is within crontab `PATH`. Otherwise, specify absolute path in your script.
3. I recommend to specify absolute path for output file to confirm whether it is generated successfully or not. Otherwise, you may get confused about file location.

Comment: Permissions are ok. Mysqldump is listed in /usr/bin, which I have in my crontab. Did you mean that? I will try with absolute path.

Comment: Finally, it is working with adding absolute path in output file. I solved problem with putting the command directly in crontab file in /etc/crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Also, -u root is wrong syntax. Should be -uroot AFAIK.

Anyway, try to log your cron entry by adding

```
>> /somefile.log 2>&1
```

to the cron line